# error when trying to send a video using requests library Python

Tags: python, video, python-requests, runtime-error, telegram-bot

I'm encountering an error code: `400` when trying to post a video file.

**Error**:

```
400 Bad Request
b'{
    "ok":false,
    "error_code":400,
    "description":"Bad Request: there is no video in the request"
}'
```

please advice what's wrong (the video file works and exist in the mentioned path)

```py
def sendVideo(bot_token,bot_chatID):
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+ bot_token +"/sendVideo";
    files = {'file': open('C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/telegram/t_video.mp4', 'rb')}
    data = {'chat_id' : bot_chatID}
    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this

```py
files = {'file': open('C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/telegram/t_video.mp4', 'rb')}
```

to that

```py
files = {'video': open('C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/telegram/t_video.mp4', 'rb')}
```

Because [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideo) needs that `video` parameter name to determine the type of media.

---

And you forgot to add `data=data` (or `params=data`) to `requests.post()` to pass `chat_id`.